# TypeError: route is undefined React Native Navigation 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I started React Native couple of days ago. Trying to create basic native apps. When i try react native navigation 5 i am gettin this error. Couldn't find similiar problem with this version of it.

```
TypeError: route is undefined
```

My Code is:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AppLogo from "./modules/AppLogo";

function HomeScreen() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: Where is this error coming from? There is no `route` in your code.

Comment: I updated new version of navigate bar which was my solution to this problem